# CSV to JSON conversion for nested records

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert records available in the csv file into JSON format so that it can be consumed by the REST Webservice.

**Sample Input File :**

```
 Id,LineNo,Amt,ReceivedDt,FromDt,ToDate
 123545,1,1000.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00
 123545,2,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00
```

**Expected output :**

```
{ "gfsAuthData": [
        {
            "Id" : "123545",
            "LineNo" :  1,
            "Amt" : "1000.00",
            "ReceivedDt" : "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "FromDt" : "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ToDate" : "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "Id" : "123545",
            "LineNo" :  2,
            "Amt" : "2000.00",
            "ReceivedDt" : "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "FromDt" : "2019-02-15T00:00:00",
            "ToDate" : "2019-02-15T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

What modifications should I do in my code to achieve about output?

**Code :**

```
import json,csv

with open('Test.csv') as f:
    inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in inputfile :
        print(json.dumps(row, indent=4))
```

**Code Output**

```
{
    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
    "Id": "123545", 
    "LineNo": "1", 
    "Amt": "1000.00", 
    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
}
{
    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
    "Id": "123545", 
    "LineNo": "2", 
    "Amt": "200.00", 
    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: Create  dict={'gfsAuthData':[]} then in your print use. dict['gsfAuthData'].append(json.dumps(row)). The intendations are just for looks.

Comment: @SimonJohansson you don't want to jsonify each row before adding them to `dict` (btw don't use `dict` as a variable name, it will shadows the builtin type), else when serializing it the contents will be doubly encoded.

Comment: fyi, your expected output isn't a dict if you didn't enclose wit curly brackets. i'm guessing it's a typo, so i'm going to edit it.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You are right. Just wanted to give some hints. A good answere is presented below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json,csv

with open('Test.csv') as f:
    inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)
    output = []
    for row in inputfile :
        j = json.dumps(row, indent=4)
        output.append(json.loads(j))

data = {'gfsAuthData': output}
print(data)
```

output:

```
{'gfsAuthData': [{'Id': '123545', 'LineNo': '1', 'Amt': '1000.00', 'ReceivedDt': '2019-02-01T00:00:00', 'FromDt': '2019-02-01T00:00:00', 'ToDate': '2019-02-01T00:00:00'}, {'Id': '123545', 'LineNo': '2', 'Amt': '200.00', 'ReceivedDt': '2019-02-01T00:00:00', 'FromDt': '2019-02-01T00:00:00', 'ToDate': '2019-02-01T00:00:00'}]}
```